# Ignite client node does not put data though server nodes to DB (with writeThrough only on server, without writeBehind)

Tags: gridgain, ignite

Could you please help me with following question:

I have the following configuration of partitioned cache cluster:

- server nodes with writeThrough enabled. They are able to write data to DB by `cacheStoreFactory=HibernateCacheStoreFactory`
- client nodes without writeThrough configuration but with `clientMode=true`

I perform put on client node, then I see, that this data is sent to server node, but server node performs put only to cache, but does not invoke cacheStoreFactory (writeThrough behaviour). So, data is only cached in cluster, but is not written to DB.

If I add writeThrough configuration to client nodes, writeThrough is invoked of course, but I would like to remove any dependencies on Hibernate from client nodes.

Also, if I enable writeBehind configuration on server side, then writeThrough functionality is invoked and server node, writes data from client node to DB asynchronously. But it does not satisfy my requirements, because I'd like to perform puts from client node in one transaction.

Is it possible to perform puts from client node to store data by server nodes with writeThrough in transaction without writeBehind?

Comment: Can you please share your configuration for both servers and clients? If you can prepare junit or `main()` program to reproduce it locally that would be perfect.

Comment: Hello, Yakov. Please tak a look at simple example:
http://www.files.com/shared/5703709862af6/igniteclientserver.zip
  
To test:  
0) Start ApplicationServer  
1) Start ApplicationClient  
2) Check changes in behaviour by [un]commenting the foollowing lines in `config-server.xml`:  
  
`<!-- [UN]COMMENT next line to enable DB updating from client nodes -->
                    <property name="writeBehindEnabled" value="true"/>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transactional cache writes to the persistence store from the node that initiated the transaction (in your case it's a client node). This is done because a transaction can potentially include entries that are stored on different nodes, and if the store will be also updated from different nodes, it would be impossible to maintain transactional consistency between cache and the database.

If you don't have access to the database on the client, you can send a closure to one of the servers and start a transaction there, like this:

```
Ignition.ignite().compute().run(new IgniteRunnable() {
    @IgniteInstanceResource
    private Ignite ignite;

    @Override public void run() {
        try (Transaction tx = ignite.transactions().txStart()) {
            // Cache operations go here...

            tx.commit();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Hello, Valentin. I suspected the same behaviour by looking into source code of Ignite, but would like to check, that it is architectural decision and not a bug. Thank you very much for answer.

Comment: @Valentin - I have a question here since we have the same use case. I didn't follow why is the database not updated when the cacheConfiguration is NOT set to write through on the client node. Isn't the setting of write through part of the cache configuration instead of the client/server node?

Comment: @AndyDufresne Cache configuration is the same on all nodes. You can't have write-through enabled on server and disabled on client.